# How to add thousands separator to a numeric string in c#?

Tags: c#, format, string-formatting, tostring, number-formatting

I want this "123456789" to this "123,456,789".

Plenty of SO answers on how to format non-string types numerically using `.Format()` and `.ToString()`. Can't find any answers on how to do coming from a **numeric string**.

I can do this way, but it's not ideal:

```
Convert.ToInt32(minPrice).ToString("N0");
```

Comment: @SystemDown - Because it's already a string and converting it to an int then back to a string seems unnecessary just to return it to string in a different format.

Comment: The alternative will be to manually go through the string to find the appropriate places to insert the commas, which could potentially be even more costly.

Comment: In addition to plausibly being even more costly, it may also be open to error. For example, if it's not actually an integer (which would throw an exception that you could fix), or has leading zeros, or a negative sign, depending on your implementation, you may produce an incorrect result and never know about it.

Comment: This already seems like a simple/neat solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Then that would makes sense why I couldn't seem to find any documentation on it despite being such a simple task. If that's the recommended way, then I'll just stick with that.

Comment: What is "simple task"? Processing integers (or other numeric types) as strings is very unusual and painful. I'd call it "rare, bad practice task" and would not expect any special documentation.

Answer (score 9):

Simply encapsulate your function, which you find isn't ideal, into an extension method.

```
public static string ToFormattedThousands(this string number)
{
    return Convert.ToInt32(number).ToString("N0");
}
```

Simply put this function into a static class and then you will be able to call it on any *string*.

**For example :**

```
string myString = "123456789".ToFormattedThousands();
```